# Snip and Sketch disabling over GPO

Tags: group-policy

i need to block Snip and Sketch on my entire Domain, is there any chance to do that using GPO? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AppLocker and [Packaged apps and packaged app installer rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/packaged-apps-and-packaged-app-installer-rules-in-applocker). Typically, you can create a rule to allow every signed appx, and add an exception for this app.

Comment: Hello, could you be more specific please?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the end goal of disabling snip and sketch would be, people can still just hit print screen and paste into MSPaint, or take pictures of the screen with their phones. As a security concern it seems a little... fuzzy.

You could however just remove it from peoples computers -

Get-AppxPackage PackageFullName | Remove-AppxPackage

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. We already disabled printscreen and snipping tool, so snip and sketch is ony left windows print screen service at users PCs.